# Error installing Recess PHP framework

Tags: php, recess

I downloaded the Recess PHP Framework source and untar in /var/www/html.

I did the modification as per readme in recess-conf.php.

```
{

    RecessConf::$defaultDatabase    
    = array( //'sqlite:' . $_ENV['dir.bootstrap'] . 'data/sqlite/default.db'    
            'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'root', 'root'    
        );    

}
```

I am getting the error when I open the google-chrome and type localhost

PDO has not been imported.

Location: `Line 19 of /var/www/html/recess/recess/database/pdo/PdoDataSource.class.php`

followed by call stack.

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Regards
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(extension_loaded ('pdo_mysql'));
```

Check `pdo_mysql` is loaded or not.